# SVG – :hover and links are not working in combination with clip-path and Firefox

Tags: css, svg, firefox, pseudo-class

For some reason, `:hover` and links are not working in combination with `clip-path` in Firefox. No problem with Chrome. I need `clip-path` to work. I know that it works without the attribute. However, it's not an option for me to remove this attribute.

Any idea why?

---

**Simplified example:**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="210" width="400">
  <style>
    path {
      fill: blue;
    }

    path:hover {
      fill: red;
    }
  </style>
  <a target="_parent" href="/test">
    <path id="triangle" clip-path="url('#triangle-clip')" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z">
      <title>Triangle</title>
    </path>
  </a>
  <clipPath id="triangle-clip">
    <use href="#triangle" />
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to break the recursion here that makes the whole thing invalid. I.e. in the version in the question the clip-path points to a `<use>` element that points to a `<path>` that has a clip-path that points to a `<use>` that points to a `<path>`...

Here's one way i.e. apply the clip-path only to the path when it's a descendant of the `<a>` element. That's ignored by the `<use>` element because the selector crosses the shadow DOM boundary.

Another way would be to replace the `<use>` element with a copy of the `<path>` its pointing to and remove the clip-path from that copy of the path, and so again fix the infinite recursion problem.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="210" width="400">
  <style>
    path {
      fill: blue;
    }

    path:hover {
      fill: red;
    }
    a > path {
      clip-path: url('#triangle-clip');
    }
  </style>
  <a target="_parent" href="/test">
    <path id="triangle" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z">
      <title>Triangle</title>
    </path>
  </a>
  <clipPath id="triangle-clip">
    <use href="#triangle" />
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case `clip-path` does nothing, so I just removed it. ANd it's important to add `@namespace`.

```css
@namespace svg url(http://www.w3.org/2000/svg);
svg|a path {
    fill: blue;
}

svg|a:hover path {
    fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="210" width="400">
  <a href="/test">
    <path id="triangle" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z">
      <title>Triangle</title>
    </path>
  </a> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this does not solve my issue.

In my example, `clip-path` does nothing because it's a simplified example. I know that if I remove this attribute it works. But I need this to work with the attribute.

And I don't think that I need to specify a namespace for my styles, because they are inside the svg tag.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if you open developer tools in Firefox you will see that you have a `shadow-root (closed)` whereas in Chrome you do not. That could possibly be why your `:hover` Pseudo-class isn't executing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/mode

Comment: Thanks. Hm... I don't see a shadow DOM at all with Firefox (visibility enabled). In Chrome there is one but with an empty element inside: `<slot name="user-agent-default-slot"></slot>`. I don't think that this is the problem. Do you?

Comment: @Mark-S Well `<use>` elements are implemented using shadow DOM in Firefox, but no it isn't the problem.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ah, now I understand. I've looked at the wrong location. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Robert Longson has pointed out your initial code has a recursion issue.

Essentially, you are clipping an svg path (triangle) by itself (... that still has to be defined by itself) – resulting in the exact same shape as the 'unclipped' version.

However, since you already used the `<use>` element, reordering your path and clipping path definitions - avoiding unnessesary recursions – might still simplify your app's code.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="210" width="400">
  <clipPath id="triangle-clip">
    <path id="triangle-path" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
  </clipPath>
  <style>
    .link-content {
      fill: blue;
        clip-path: url('#triangle-clip');
    }
    a:hover .link-content{
      fill: red;
    }
  </style>
  <a class="link" target="_parent" href="/test">
    <title>Triangle</title>
    <use class="link-content" href="#triangle-path" />
  </a>
</svg>
```